# unable to boot into windows 10 after ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, menu

i have windows 10 loader option in my boot menu
but still if i select it the screen just goes blank for 2 seconds and returns to boot menu whereas if i select ubuntu it loads perfectly....
here is my bootinfo  http://paste2.org/DLUEM03C
I have tried boot repair also

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Windows Bootable USB/DVD ? If yes, try to repair windows. People do face problems after dual booting Linux & Windows.

Repairing might just work !

Another way,
GRUB Option, as mentioned by @maxcampman

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestion in this post? It could be an issue with GRUBs configuration.

[Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)